# Save image that has been segmented in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation, fuzzy-c-means

I would like to know how can we save an image that has been segmented (using fuzzy c-means method) in MATLAB where the end product are images of each cluster group. I would like to save the images to use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you just want to save an image, this should be independent on how you produces that.

If I understood correctly you just have to use the function

```
imwrite(M, filename)
```

Where M is the matrix containing your image data. You just need to do this for each matrix/image you have.

Then you can reload the image from filename using imread.

```
imread(filename)
```

Note that if you want to specify the format for imwrite and not obtain it via the filename extension, you just to add an additional parameter as follow:

```
imwrite(M, filename, format)
```

Comment: i am just curious, after using imwrite, where did that image save? any specific folder or i need to assign to that specific folder?

Comment: @syakey You can specifiy a full path in 'filename', if you just put a name (e.g. 'test.png') it will go straight to your MATLAB working directory.